# Making unique key case insensitive

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

This is my schema for mysql table, im using mysql 5

```
--
-- Table structure for table `DATA_USER_ROLE`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DATA_USER_ROLE`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `DATA_USER_ROLE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `VAL_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CREATION_TIME` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ROLE_TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STORAGE_TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BV_AC_ROLE_KEY_IDX` (`NAME`,`VAL_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Needed UNIQUE KEY case in sensitive,

It should allow to enter the value like('a',0)  & ('A', 0)

tried changing collation to latin_1 and latin_generic_ci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest is to add `BINARY` on the DDL statement,

```
`NAME` varchar(128) BINARY NOT NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b93e5)

Comment: @J W : i changed collation for NAME aatribute to utf8_bin. Im using SQLYOG. Same  issue is there.

Comment: how about adding `BINARY`? what do you mean by same issue?

Comment: How can this solve the problem? It's even not using `UNIQUE` constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you need case sensitive:

```
ALTER TABLE `DATA_USER_ROLE` CHANGE `NAME` `NAME` VARCHAR( 128 )
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

If you need case insensitive:

```
ALTER TABLE `DATA_USER_ROLE` CHANGE `NAME` `NAME` VARCHAR( 128 )
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: In any case, this answer would be far more helpful with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A case insensitive `COLLATE` can be added on the whole table, i.e. every text column in the table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `DATA_USER_ROLE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `VAL_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CREATION_TIME` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ROLE_TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STORAGE_TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BV_AC_ROLE_KEY_IDX` (`NAME`,`VAL_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

In this case, the `_ci` at the end of the `COLLATE` stands for `case insensitive`.

This follows Monolune's recommendation for CHARSET and COLLATE from https://www.monolune.com/mysql-utf8-charsets-and-collations-explained/ and
https://www.monolune.com/what-is-the-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci-collation/

These are the defauts since MySQL 8.0.1 .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in such a way..

```
create table testTable (col_name varchar(100) character set utf8 
collate utf8_bin not null ) Engine=innodb default charset=utf8
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use utf8_general_ci (case insensitive) charset by default for your db or only for one row, if you needed